# Exclude a combination from SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple SQL query

```
SELECT NAME, FAMILY_NAME, AGE, SALARY, LOCATION
FROM TABLE
WHERE AGE > 34 and SALARY > 40000
```

and this works fine. But, I wish to exclude all the entry where NAME = 'ROBERTO' and FAMILY_NAME = 'D_SILVA'. How can I do this?

I am trying to impose not equal over NAME and FAMILY_NAME but that is excluding all the entries were Name = Roberto or FAMILY_NAME = 'D_SILVA'

Comment: Do you want to exclude all where those are **both** true, or any one **or** the other is true? You could also show sample data and desired results. But you already wrote in English what you want to exclude, so just translate that to SQL... `and not (NAME = 'ROBERTO' and FAMILY_NAME = 'D_SILVA')`, or maybe `or` instead of `and` as I said previously.

Answer (score 2):

By using parentheses, you can combine the filters. By nesting these filters (by adding parentheses) shown below and putting the "AND" keyword between the filters, you make sure both conditions have to be true.

```
SELECT [NAME], [FAMILY_NAME], [AGE], [SALARY], [LOCATION]
FROM [dbo].[TABLE]
WHERE [AGE] > 34 
AND [SALARY] > 40000
AND NOT ([NAME] = 'ROBERTO' AND [FAMILY_NAME] = 'D_SILVA')
```

I recommend reading more about [Logical Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186992(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Some explanation of how your answer works would greatly approve this answer. The OP should be able to learn from this, not just copy/past and be glad it works